# Refactor methods, returning sorted arrays

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have two methods, which do exactly same thing - fill in arrayOfStrings and arrayOfInts,
and have identical code, except the last line:

```
public static string[] GetSortedStrings() 
{
    // (here are several lines of code to fill in those two arrays ...)
    Array.Sort(arrayOfStrings, arrayOfInts);
    return arrayOfStrings;
}


public static int[] GetSortedInts() 
{
    // (here are exactly same lines of code to get those arrays)
    Array.Sort(arrayOfStrings, arrayOfInts);
    return arrayOfInts;
}
```

Question is - can I extract this common part, which fills those arrays, for reuse in both methods?

Comment: Why this is even a question? *can I extract this common part...?* Do it right away. When you find duplicate code, refactor it. [Don’t repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would consider something like here:

```
public static string[] GetSortedStrings() 
{
    var tuple = fillArrays();
    Array.Sort(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    return tuple.Item1;
}

public static int[] GetSortedInts() 
{
    var tuple = fillArrays();
    Array.Sort(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    return tuple.Item2;
}

public Tuple<string[],int[]> fillArrays() 
{
    // (here are several lines of code to fill in those two arrays ...)
    return Tuple.Create(strings, ints);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
public static string[] GetSortedStrings() 
{
    doSomething(ref arrayOfStrings, ref arrOfInts);
    return arrayOfStrings;
}


public static int[] GetSortedInts() 
{
    doSomething(ref arrayOfStrings, ref arrOfInts);
    return arrayOfInts;
}

public static void doSomething(ref string[] arrayOfString, ref int[] arrayOfInt) {
    // do your common stuff here
}
```

In Visual Studio you may just right-click a piece of code and refactor it (Refactor-->Extract Method)

Comment: ref is somewat an antipattern in c#